# How to resolve GRASS error "Execution failed: 'gproj -p' "?

Tags: grass-gis

I installed the WinGRASS-6.4.0-1-Setup.exe 55M from http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/binary/mswindows/native/. I'm using a x64. After installation, I tried opening the demoLocation but it failed and displayed the error: Execution failed: 'gproj -p'. How do I resolve it?

Comment: You may want to try the OSGeo4W version of the program, or try the WinGRASS list -- I see a listing you may have already posted there, in which case you likely don't need this post, the actual developers will give their feedback there

Comment: Do you manage to enter GRASS anyway? if so, please run in the command line 'g.proj -p' and watch out for errors. I suspect that either the GDAL or the PROJ installation is incomplete.

Comment: I did not manage to enter GRASS. When I close the error message: Execution failed: 'gproj -p', the GRASS program suddenly terminates.

Comment: are you using the TclTl, WxPython or Text interface? does it fail similarly in all three without reporting further errors?

Comment: since this is a new installation I am using the wxpython interface. However once I load the demolocation I am confronted immediately with errors.

Comment: You may try if the "cs2cs" binary of PROJ4 works as well as "gdalinfo" from GDAL.

Comment: Have you gotten this to work yet, teamAngat?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try with a new version: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/binary/mswindows/

Comment: I wonder why this remains tagged "unanswered" nontheless answers were posted...?